# Why is this plugin not working?

Tags: plugins

I am currently learning WordPress Plugin Development. I was trying to insert data into a custom table by means of a plugin. Such that, when an action hook is fired, the data is inserted. It is a pretty simple code here but not getting executed although on debugging I found that the commented echo statement within the function does get executed.

Here is the code -

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: What the wpdb
Description: Making use of wpdb
Version: 1.0
Author: Navin Nagpal
License: GPLv2
*/
add_action('wp_head','nn_do_dbstuff');

function nn_do_dbstuff(){
global $wpdb;
//echo 'Text';
$values = array(
    'column1'=>'Navin',
    'column2'=>22);
$formats_values = array('%s','%d');
$wpdb->insert($wpdb->custom,$values,$formats_values);
}
?>
```

My table is named wp_custom and it has three fields including the 'id' field which is the primary key

Comment: change `$wpdb->custom` to `'wp_custom'` and see what will happen.

Comment: You need to make sure that *you* have set the `$wpdb->custom` variable; this is not automatic. You should use `$wpdb->prefix . 'custom'` to build the table name with the proper database prefix

Comment: Hey thanx for the answer. Working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wpdb->custom` should be `"{$wpdb->prefix}custom"`

`$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format );`
 take three params where 1st is table name. you should avoid wp as its not necessary that prefix will always be wp_ instead use `$wpdb->prefix` to get table prefix,
`"{$wpdb->prefix}custom"` 
will output wp_custom (given prefix is wp for your site)